# If I had some ETH on the exchange - shall I own ETH and ETC (Ethereum Classic) now?

Tags: exchanges

I cannot recall the exact dates and balances, but in principle - is my assumption corrent?

**EDIT:** Comment is right, it's a duplicate.

**TODO:** Check accounts and balances, and why the heck I didn't think about it untill now?

Comment: Hi there. I think this is basically the same as this previous question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7445/i-own-ether-should-i-also-own-ether-classic-are-they-one-in-the-same/8335#8335

Comment: I'll add an answer to that previous question with details of the exact dates, and mark your question as duplicate.